# How do i create a function that generates 3 dice rolls in C++

Tags: c++

I need to create a function that generates 3 dice rolls, I've actually got a piece of code that generates 3 dice rolls but I need to call it from a function. Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>

using namespace std;

int cash = 90000;
int main()
{
    int wager;
    int r;

    // dealer's die
    int dealer1;
    int dealer2;
    int dealer3;

    // your die
    int mdice1;
    int mdice2;
    int mdice3;
    //your money



    cout << "Wager up boy!" << endl;
    cin >> wager;
    while (wager < 100 || wager > 90000)
    {
        cout << "Minimum wager is 100; Maximum wager is 90000 ";
        cin >> wager;
    }
    cout << "You wagered: " << wager << endl;
    cout << "You have " << cash - wager << " remaining" << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Dealer will now roll the dice" << endl;

    srand(time(NULL));
    dealer1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
    dealer2 = rand() % 6 + 1;
    dealer3 = rand() % 6 + 1;

    cout << "Dealer rolled the following: " << endl;
    cout << dealer1 << "-" << dealer2 << "-" << dealer3 << endl;

    cout << "It's your turn to roll the dice." << endl;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Press any key to roll the dice" << endl;
    cin >> r;

    mdice1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
    mdice2 = rand() % 6 + 1;
    mdice3 = rand() % 6 + 1;

    cout << "You rolled the following: " << endl;
    cout << mdice1 << "-" << mdice2 << "-" << mdice3 << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Are you using a C++11 capable compiler?

Comment: I think you'll enjoy reading this: http://www.redblobgames.com/articles/probability/damage-rolls.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirement isnt very clear! 
Supposing you want the dice roll part in a function.
Write a function like this

```
int dice_roll()
{
  return (rand() % 6 + 1);
}
```

and call this function like this

```
dealer1=dice_roll();
```

Comment: It's working, thanks dude, oh and sorry if my code's composition was weird.

Comment: @elburatski no problem!

Comment: Would it be possible to modify this to make the function roll 3 dice, instead of calling it 3 times?

Comment: @elburatski yes, Barmar's answer is doing that. In that, he is passing three integers as reference(means the changes made in function will also reflect on actual value) to the function that need to store the dice result, then inside the function he is assigning the data to them.

Comment: @elburatski but then you wont be able to use it for single dice roll

Answer (score 1):

Tanuj Yadav has the right idea, you look for the smallest repeated section of code, then you encapsulate that as a function. e.g. the basic repeated unit is effectively

```
int dice = rand () % 6 + 1
```

so you can make a function. you need to get an "int" back, and you want the usage to look like this

```
int dice = roll_die();
```

to make a function, the basic pattern is:

```
return_type name(parameter_type parameter_name, etc)
```

so your return type is "int", name is "roll_die", and parameter is optional. I would use number of sides as the parameter.

```
int roll_die()
{
    return rand () % 6 + 1;
}
```

or

```
int roll_die(int sides = 6)
{
    return rand () % sides + 1;
}
```

^ This one assumes sides is 6 if you don't specify otherwise, but can be used for any-sided dice without needing new code.

This maintains the concept of only repeating the same code *once* per program. You can make a function that rolls more than one die, but it should call the "roll_die" function itself rather than repeating "rand () % 6 + 1" three times. Repetition is bad form. You can get away with it in real-world coding, but you should not be lazy when you're being **tested** on the concept of functions. Convert any repeated code to a common function.

The next level is to "roll three dice". Some of your choices include returning a pointer, a struct or a std::vector. Pointers have been shown in other answers but I highly recommend against those implementations. If you return memory created with malloc, it can cause errors if the client doesn't call "free". When making a function, you should NOT assume that the calling code has special knowledge. You should error-proof the function code itself.

For that reason I suggest either returning a std::vector or a custom struct with the three dice rolls. e.g.

```
struct three_dice
{
    int roll1, roll2, roll3;
}
```

Or this version which uses an array:

```
struct three_dice
{
    int roll[3];
}
```

Then your function returns a three_dice object that it makes:

```
three_dice roll_three_dice()
{
    three_dice temp;
    temp.roll1 = roll_die();
    temp.roll2 = roll_die();
    temp.roll3 = roll_die();
    return temp;
}
```

Or like this with the array version:

```
three_dice roll_three_dice()
{
    three_dice temp;
    temp.roll[0] = roll_die();
    temp.roll[1] = roll_die();
    temp.roll[2] = roll_die();
    return temp;
}
```

Then, instead of making separate dice1, dice2, dice3 variables, you make two "three_dice" objects, and have them copy their values from the return type of the roll_three_dice function, which itself calls the roll_die function three times:

```
three_dice dealer;
three_dice player;
dealer = roll_three_dice();
player = roll_three_dice();
```

And you can get the values out like this:

```
cout << "You rolled the following: " << endl;
cout << player.roll1 << "-" << player.roll2 << "-" << player.roll3 << endl;
```

Or if you used an array instead of the three names:

```
cout << "You rolled the following: " << endl;
cout << player.roll[0] << "-" << player.roll[1] << "-" << player.roll[2] << endl;
```

This code is safer because there is no "malloc" so no possible memory leaks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a function that returns multiple values, use reference parameters.

```
void roll_3_dice(int &dice1, int &dice2, int &dice3) {
    dice1 = rand() % 6 + 1;
    dice2 = rand() % 6 + 1;
    dice3 = rand() % 6 + 1;
    return;
}
```

Then you would call it like this:

```
roll_3_dice(dealer1, dealer2, dealer3);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std; 

int* get_dealer_roll()
{
  int* dealer = (int*)malloc(3*sizeof(int));

  srand (time(NULL));
  *(dealer+0) = rand() % 6 + 1;
  *(dealer+1) = rand() % 6 + 1;
  *(dealer+2) = rand() % 6 + 1;

  return dealer;
}

int* get_mdice_roll()
{

   int* mdice = (int*)malloc(3*sizeof(int));

  srand (time(NULL));
  *(mdice+0) = rand() % 6 + 1;
  *(mdice+1) = rand() % 6 + 1;
  *(mdice+2) = rand() % 6 + 1;

  return mdice;
}
int main()
{
int wager; 
int r;


//your money

int cash = 90000;


cout << "Wager up boy!"<< endl;
cin >> wager;
while (wager < 100 || wager > 90000)
{
cout << "Minimum wager is 100; Maximum wager is 90000 ";
cin >> wager;
}
cout << "You wagered: " << wager << endl;
cout << "You have " << cash - wager << " remaining" << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << "Dealer will now roll the dice" << endl;

int* dealer = get_dealer_roll();

cout << "Dealer rolled the following: " << endl;
cout << *(dealer+0) << "-" << *(dealer+1) << "-" << *(dealer+2) << endl;

cout << "It's your turn to roll the dice." << endl;
cout << endl; 
cout << "Press any key to roll the dice" << endl;
cin >> r;

int* mdice = get_mdice_roll();

cout << "You rolled the following: " << endl;
cout << *(mdice+0) << "-" << *(mdice+1) << "-" << *(mdice+2) << endl;
system ("pause");
free(mdice);
free(dealer);
}
```

Comment: Global variables, really?

Comment: i'm new to this kinda thing

Comment: This is not a good solution.There's no need to bring pointers into this. Also you didn't create a function for the core concept of rolling a *single* dice. Why have the same dice rolling repeated 6 times? And why have separate functions for player dice and dealer dice? What if we want a version rolling four dice, are you going to make two new functions for the dealer and player for *every* number of dice that could be rolled? Voted down as this is just awful coding.What you could have done is just make a unified"roll X dice" function that returns any number of dice for either player or dealer.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a hint: you already did because main() is a function. Main is a function that returns an integer, which is not included in your code(return 0;). A void function using all of your code will work.

```
void diceGame()
{
    everything you have in main
}

int main()
{
    diceGame();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
void diceGame(); //prototype

int main()
{
    diceGame();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void diceGame()
{
    everything you have in main
}
```

Comment: then we should never use functions, bcz everything is already in a function(main).

Comment: No, functions are very useful. I am saying he can make a function out of everything he put in main. Main is a function.

Comment: I think the point is that he has several places in the main function where he rolls 3 dice. He would like to move that into a separate function so he doesn't have to repeat the code each time. That's the point of splitting things up into functions.

Comment: Barmar's got it right, sorry 'bout my code's structure, i'm really new to this so i'm just following what i see online/ what i'm taught

Comment: Precisely right, the whole and/or it's parts. I agree.